# How to get this line of jQuery to validate as XHTML strict

Tags: jquery, html, xhtml-1.0-strict, xhtml

I have this bit of jQuery at the top of my page (used for a simple image carousel):

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $("#slider").easySlider({
        prevText:'<div id="backarrow">Back</div>',
        nextText:'<div id="nextarrow">View Other Projects</div>',
        orientation:'horizontal'
    });
});
```

however, I can't get it to validate XHTML strict:

> Line 12, Column 33: document type does
>   not allow element "div" here

Any ideas?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $("#slider").easySlider({
            prevText:'<div id="backarrow">Back</div>',
            nextText:'<div id="nextarrow">View Other Projects</div>',
            orientation:'horizontal'
    });
});
/* ]]> */
</script>
```

This tells the validator to interpret the script as character data, not markup, and thus it won't parse the structure of the CDATA block. Wikipedia [has more info](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA).

Answer (score -1):

It has nothing to with JQuery.  Just surround the JS with comments (CDATA as ceejayoz gave should work too).

Comment: Comments, if the XHTML is processed as XHTML, will comment out the script so it will not run. Do NOT use them for this.

Comment: David, I just tested in Firefox 3 with a XHTML 1.0 Strict (fully validating) page containing : <script type="text/javascript"> <!-- alert("foo"); --> </script> You're simply wrong.

Comment: Did you serve the document as application/xhtml+xml? I'm betting not. If you serve it as text/html then it will be processed as HTML not XHTML. The rules for HTML are not the same as those for XHTML.

Comment: I stand corrected.  When served as XML (note, this is not required to be valid XHTML), the script will not run.